# Class based directional indicator

Tags: python, list, class, append, range

I'm creating a class based directional indicator that given a number of days (`n_days`) and a list of numbers, it gives the (number of numbers out of the most recent `n_days` on which the number was higher than the previous number minus the `n_days` out of the previous `n_days` on which the number went down). So if the number in the list increases I want it to return `+1`, if it decreases I want it to return `-1`, otherwise it should be `0` so the first number should always be `0` since you can't compare it to anything. Then based on `n_days` I basically want to take the sum of the of the recent n_days, so for example in a list of `[1,2,2,1,2,1]` the change should be `[0,+1,0,-1,1,-1]` and if I want the sum of the change in the 2 recent numbers for each day so it should be `[0,+1,-1,0,+1,0]` because on the first day there is only 0, on the second day you take the sum of the most recent two days `0+(+1)=1`, the third day `(+1)+0=+1`, the fourth day `0+(-1)=-1` and so forth. Here is my code that's not working:

```
class Directionalindicator():
    def __init__(self, n_days, list_of_prices):
        self.n_days = n_days
        self.list_of_prices = list_of_prices

    def calculate(self):
        change = []
        for i in range(len(self.list_of_prices)):
            if self.list_of_prices[i-1] < self.list_of_prices[i]:
                change.append(1)
            elif self.list_of_prices[i-1] > self.list_of_prices[i]:
                change.append(-1)
            else:
                change.append(0)
        directional = []
        for i in range(len(change)):
            directional.append(sum(change[i+1-self.n_days:i+1]))
        return directional
```

testing it with:

```
y = Directionalindicator(2,[1,2,2,1,2,1])

y.calculate()
```

should return:

```
[0,+1,+1,-1,0,0]
```

and it does.

But testing it with:

```
y = Directionalindicator(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

y.calculate()
```

should return

```
[0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

but it returns

```
[0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

I printed change to see what it was doing and the first value is a -1 instead of a 0. Also, the code in one of the answers works using zip, but I don't understand why mine doesn't work for that list from 1-10.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: + Could you fix your indentation?

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the change to your question. Had you commented on it that you were having trouble implementing the solution, I would have added this sooner. If you have found my answer useful, it would be nice to up-vote or even accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison

```
i > i-1
```

will *always* be `True`. You are comparing each price to itself minus one, which will always be smaller. Instead, you should be comparing pairs of prices. `zip` is useful for this:

```
change = [0] # first price always zero change
for a, b in zip(self.list_of_prices, self.list_of_prices[1:]):
    if a < b: # price went up
        change.append(1)
    elif a > b: # price went down
        change.append(-1)
    else: # price stayed the same
        change.append(0)
```

When you plug this into your code and use your example

```
Directionalindicator(2, [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1])
```

you get:

```
change == [0, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1]
directional == [0, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0]
```

This seems to be correct according to your initial statement of the rules, but for some reason doesn't match your "expected output" `[0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0]` from the end of your question.

---

The reason your edit doesn't work is that you are using an index `i` on the list. When `i == 0`, `i-1 == -1`. When used as an index `list_of_prices[-1]`, this gives you the last element in the list. Therefore `change` contains `[-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, as it compares `1` with `10`, not `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` as you expected.

Comment: So should I just use zip then? It still confuses me how it worked for the first test though using indexes.

Comment: It worked by luck for the first test - because the first test both started and ended with `1`! You can use `zip` or start your indexing from 1: `for i in range(1, len(...)):`