# Difficulty with index comparison logic

Tags: python

I'm creating a class based signal generator that given a list of prices and a list of averages it creates a 'buy' of 'sell' signal on a given day if the price from that day is greater than the average but the day before it wasn't greater so basically when the price crosses over the average it gives a sell signal and a buy signal when the price crosses under the averages (it's lower than the average on a day, but the day before it wasn't) this is my code but it just returns a list with empty strings from the 3rd case.

```
class Simplemovingaverage_signals():
    def __init__(self, list_of_prices, list_of_averages):
        self.list_of_prices = list_of_prices
        self.list_of_averages = list_of_averages

    def calculate(self):
        signals = []
        for i, j in zip(self.list_of_prices, self.list_of_averages):
            if i > j and not i-1 > j-1:
            signals.append('Sell')
            elif i < j and not i-1 < j-1:
                signals.append('Buy')
            else:
                signals.append('')
        return signals
```

Comment: The error you're getting is likely a SyntaxError and has nothing to do with the actual purpose of the code.  Regardless you should post the actual traceback you got.

Comment: @Iguananaut I fixed the Syntax, but it doesn't return the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *exactly the same problem* here you had in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850041/class-based-directional-indicator):

```
if i > j and not i-1 > j-1:
```

How could this ever be `True`? If `i` is larger than `j`, then `i-1` will be larger than `j-1`.

I think you keep trying to use the items from the list as indices, trying to compare each value to the previous value. Therefore you probably want:

```
for i1, i2, j1, j2 in zip(prices, prices[1:], aves, aves[1:]):
    if i2 > j2 and i1 <= j1:
```

i.e. checking whether the price has gone from below or equal to the average to above the average.